# compound index not being used on simple query

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm running this query, and it seems to be doing a table scan , rather than using the relevant index..

```
select count(*) from pages where charity_id=447 and provider_id=1
```

this is the explain:

```
Aggregate  (cost=509163.46..509163.47 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=384314.621..384314.622 rows=1 loops=1)", 
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on pages  (cost=32850.60..505318.05 rows=1538163 width=0) (actual time=14952.277..379428.537 rows=1876399 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: ((charity_id = 447) AND (provider_id = 1))"
"        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 2053204"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_pages_on_charity_id_and_provider_id  (cost=0.00..32466.06 rows=1538163 width=0) (actual time=14697.258..14697.258 rows=1910571 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: ((charity_id = 447) AND (provider_id = 1))"
"Total runtime: 384318.977 ms"]
```

The indexes are:

```
"pages", ["category_id"], name: "index_pages_on_category_id", using: :btree
"pages", ["charity_id", "first_donation_at"], name: "index_pages_on_charity_id_and_first_donation_at", using: :btree
"pages", ["charity_id", "provider_id"], name: "index_pages_on_charity_id_and_provider_id", using: :btree
"pages", ["charity_id", "total_online_cents"], name: "index_pages_on_charity_id_and_total_online_cents", using: :btree
"pages", ["charity_id", "updated_at"], name: "index_pages_on_charity_id_and_updated_at", using: :btree
"pages", ["charity_id"], name: "index_pages_on_charity_id", using: :btree
... some irrelevant ones clipped ...
"pages", ["provider_id"], name: "index_pages_on_provider_id", using: :btree
"pages", ["provider_uid"], name: "index_pages_on_provider_uid", using: :btree
```

Any thoughts as to why this seems to be doing a table scan, and not using the compound index?

edit, a couple of examples:

Page Load (2.4ms)

```
SELECT  pages.* 
FROM pages  
WHERE pages.charity_id = 447 AND pages.provider_id = 1  
ORDER BY pages.id ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Page Load (271604.8ms)

```
SELECT  pages.* 
FROM pages  
WHERE pages.charity_id = 447 AND pages.provider_id = 2  
ORDER BY pages.id ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Not sure why the first one is fast, second one is slow, despite being the same filter options?

Comment: The index is used: `Bitmap Index Scan on ...`. I guess you want to ask why it is not used alone without touching the table?

Comment: I guess I'm just confused as to qhy it's so slow, whilst being indexed?

Comment: So, the original plan shows a very slow query for `charity_id = 447 AND provider_id = 2`, where you count about the half of your whole table.  It's still very slow for that many rows, but there is no wonder it does not use the index.  With the last two queries you don't show a query plan, one can only guess without them.

Comment: Sorry, above I meant `charity_id = 447 AND provider_id = 1`, of course.

Comment: Please provide proper information or delete this question. Consider instructions in the tag-info to [postgresql-performance].